Can PowerBi be embedded in a .Net webpage as web component?
Hi is there a way with which power bi dashboard/reports can be integrated in a .net webpage as web components. We do not want to use iframe to embed the reports.
Please help.

Yes, It can be embedded, a good place to start would be here https://playground.powerbi.com/en-us/

Thanks for your input , can you throw more light on it. I went to the developer sandbox and imported my report then i could see 2 options for code typescript and javascript . Does that mean if i use this code in my application it will embed the report in my application. It would be great if you can provide any weblink to refer. Thanks :)

Refer to .NET Developer Samples Code to get a working example on how embed the Power BI Report using .NET.
